# Custom Form issue - NGM Forum thread section in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I am using the external module, [NGM Forum](https://github.com/Jetski5822/NGM.Forum).

In thread create form the **Save** button is not inside the `<form>` tag.

So when I press save it's not submitting the form.

How can I get the Save button back inside the form?

Please refer to the attached images:

[image: error thread 1]
[image: error thread 2]

Answer (score 0):

### Placement.info

It could be that you have customised the form somehow with your placement.info file and moved the save button down.

### Edit form on create form?

Looking at the code from your screenshot it looks like you are on the `/Create/` action, and your form tag confirms this with the `id="thread-create"`. [Code](https://github.com/Jetski5822/NGM.Forum/blob/baceffd18418d59a7d81803c0e82415bb7bc648e/Views/Thread/Create.cshtml#L11).

But the Save button is for the [Edit action with submit.Save](https://github.com/Jetski5822/NGM.Forum/blob/baceffd18418d59a7d81803c0e82415bb7bc648e/Controllers/ForumAdminController.cs#L126).

You must have made some mistakes with your changes before this point so you will need to explain how you built this form further I think for anyone to help you resolve it.